# loop to generate words to until a user specified word is matched

Tags: string, loops, for-loop, random, match

I need to write a program that prompts a user for a word, then generates random strings of letters of that length until the word is generated and show how many tries it took. here is the code i have so far:

```
  System.out.println("(Match a word) Enter a word to be matched randomly: ");
         String userWord = input.next();
         String lowerUserWord = userWord.toLowerCase();   

         int wordLength = lowerUserWord.length();
            System.out.println("Your word has " + wordLength + " letters");

         while (lowerUserWord != ) {
           //somehow generate random words of the length 'wordLength'
        }
```

Comment: So if i start with ```hallo```, i would at average wait for ```5^26 / 2 = 11881376 / 2 = 5940688 ~ 6 million``` guessings? I think i got no time for that ;-). For your project: Learn how to use PRNGs (random-generators) to select uniformly from an arrray. Then create an array of all chars and implement some function selecting one of these chars (using the PRNG). Call this for every needed char!

Comment: Don't try to guess the whole word at once.  Use something like Hangman to guess one letter at a time.